# ArtoolKit modyfing code

Tags: ubuntu, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I am making  avery general question.

I download ArtoolKIt from this link (Software y Extras) [ArtoolKit](http://www.librorealidadaumentada.com/)
and I use this command in terminal in ubuntu:

```
apt-get install freeglut3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

libxi-dev libxmu-dev libjpeg-dev

And then ./Configure and $make.

So after these I have some simple Augmented Reality projects inside bin folder that can be executed. The problem is I cannot find where to modify these simple projects. LIke they are prepared for execution but I cannot find their code to make modifications.

Has somebody experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to get the sources and everything from this repository https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5 as it holds the most recent changes to ARToolKit. The link you shared is not working for me so I cannot verify the package you got. You can get the building on Linux information from here https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/wiki/Building-on-Linux

All the code for the examples is available in the examples directory inside the repository: https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/tree/master/examples

I recommend to start with [simpleLite] (https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/tree/master/examples/simpleLite)

As it is the easiest place to start, from my point of view.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: so I see that you are teh only one who has some knowledge bout ArtoolKit here! Is there another way to compile these codes except for $make? Cause this is outputing teh error :No such file or directory for me. Thanks in advanc!

Comment: From which location `pwd` do you call make. You are calling `make` not `$make` right? Have you followed the building-on-linux guide?

Comment: It was just a problem with routes! Nothing more! All the people that have teh same problem have to control the routes. Everything's fine! If you like the answer @Thor_Bux please vote my question cause I have been banned for 6 months! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by routes?

Comment: Yes, sure! So inside "Example" folder you should have the c file, the make file and a folder called data for this to work. Meanwhile I had another folder inside folder Examples that contained these 3 things. So be aware of that xD